# UDP request command format for collectd

Tags: ruby, udp, metrics, statsd, collectd

I am trying to send a UDP request through collectd to Signalfx. The UDP request contains metric name, metric value, metric type, and most importantly, **custom tags**. The custom tags should contain key-value pairs of several dimensions and we should be able to filter our metric on Signalfx according to those tags. What is the message format of the UDP command that will be sent along with custom tags to Signalfx?

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about using collectd as a UDP statsd daemon that then forwards your data to SignalFx, as described at https://github.com/signalfx/integrations/tree/master/collectd-statsd ?

If so, you should read this section in particular: https://github.com/signalfx/integrations/tree/master/collectd-statsd#adding-dimensions-to-statsd-metrics, which talks about how to add custom tags/dimensions to your metrics when writing to that statsd UDP endpoint.

As described, the following line:

```
statsd.[foo=bar,dim=val]test:1|g
```

will emit a datapoint with a value of `1` for a `statsd.test` gauge metric with the `foo=bar` and `dim=val` dimensions.